# ionic v3 proxy configuration for running on android device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, proxy, cors, ionic-cli

Proxy settings work when I run locally on the browser.

When I run it on the device using:

```
ionic cordova run android --device --livereload
```

I get the error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:5984/mobilehosstest: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://172.22.4.13:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

The question is why is it trying to load from `localhost:5984`. If it was loading from `localhost:8100` or `http://172.22.4.13:8100`, the proxies would work as they work in the browser.

Its something to do with the livereload server but I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Running the following command adds a proxy when running on an Android device.

```
ionic cordova run android -lc
```

You have to have your Android device connected to your computer. The following are my environment configurations.

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

Also, make sure your **ionic.config.json** has the proxy added.